# How can I get PurifyCSSPlugin to remove my unused css in Angular6?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, webpack

I'm trying to remove a lot of unused css within my sass files in my Angular 6 project.

I'm learned that there is a webpack plugin called [PurifyCss](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/purifycss-webpack).

Currently now, I'm unable to eject the webpack config in my angular project so I'm using [ngw](https://github.com/Angular-RU/angular-cli-webpack) to help add the necessary plugins (to angular's webpack config) needed to extract the unused css in my sass files.

**ngw.config.ts**

```
import * as webpack from 'webpack';
import { Path } from '@angular-devkit/core';
import { NormalizedBrowserBuilderSchema } from '@angular-devkit/build-angular';
import * as PurifyCSSPlugin from 'purifycss-webpack';
import * as path from 'path';
import * as glob from 'glob';

export type WebpackOptions<T = NormalizedBrowserBuilderSchema> = {
    root: Path,
    projectRoot: Path,
    options: T;
};

const command = process.argv[2].toLowerCase();

export default function (config: webpack.Configuration, options: WebpackOptions) {
    if (command === 'test') {
            console.log('Test configuration is running');
    }
    console.log('To modify webpack build, you can use ngw.config.ts');
    console.log('check path:', glob.sync(path.join(__dirname, 'src/**/*.html')));
    config.plugins.push(
        new PurifyCSSPlugin({
            // This was suggested to help it actually remove the css from: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/purifycss-webpack/issues/54
            // Although there is an error of: Error: data['resolveExtensions'] should NOT have additional properties
            resolveExtensions: ['.html', '.js'],
            // This causes the build to run but does not remove the unused css
            paths: glob.sync(path.join(__dirname, 'src/**/*.html'))
        }),
    );
    return config;
}
```

Using the paths property alone doesn't work and it was suggested to add resolveExtensions from [here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/purifycss-webpack/issues/54).

Although this leads to the error below when doing a `ngw prod build`:

> Error: data['resolveExtensions'] should NOT have additional properties

How can I configure the PurifyCSSPlugin to remove unused css within sass files in an Angular-6-cli environement?

Note: I don't have much experience with webpack, so I'm not sure if this config only works with css files instead of scss files. (If so please correct me).

Thanks

Comment: Why not use Angular-CLI? It helps you build your project, generates a boilerplate, components and services, then compiles everything with minification, tree-shaking, AoT and all

Comment: I do use Angular-CLI, but the prod build will not extract my unused css. I want to be able to do this, so I can just use large css utility libraries and just take what I need in the final build.